# How to make an automatic slide show with play and pause buttons?

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

In my application I want an automatic slide show with play and pause buttons.

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+slideshow

Comment: Google it - there are like a gazillion slideshow scripts! (thanks c0mrade, just learning the SO ropes)

Comment: http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

- See this sample http://www.slidesjs.com/examples/playing/
- Use this JS lib http://www.slidesjs.com/

do like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="slides">
      <img src="img/example-slide-1.jpg">
      <img src="img/example-slide-2.jpg">
      <img src="img/example-slide-3.jpg">
      <img src="img/example-slide-4.jpg"">
    </div>
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.slidesjs.com/examples/playing/js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        play: {
          active: true,
          auto: true,
          interval: 4000,
          swap: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          restartDelay: 2500
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```